# python permutations of list backtracking

Tags: python

I need to write a python program that prints in ascending order all permutation of list of numbers. I have to write two programs. One with repeat and one without repeat. For example: list is [1,1,3] so first function output will be:

```
1,1,3
1,3,1
3,1,1
```

and second func output will be:

```
1,1,3
1,1,3
1,3,1
1,3,1
3,1,1
3,1,1
```

right now I wrote this code but I have trouble with the Asc order:

```
def perm1 (mylist, newlist):

    if len(mylist)==0:
        print ','.join(map(str,newlist))
    for i in range (0, len(mylist)):
        newlist.append(mylist.pop(i))
        perm1(mylist, newlist)
        mylist.insert(i, newlist.pop())
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: there is an `itertools.permutations` function that will return all of them

Comment: Looks like homework.  Are you sure you have the right interpretation of "with and without repetition"?  Just printing something twice is trivial.  Do you think the question might be referring to the difference between permutations and combinations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119566/python-lists-numbers/28120191#28120191 remove the set check to keep repeats

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) would be perfect for this! You could use it like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

def perm1(my_list):
    return " ".join(",".join((str(si) for si in i)) for i in sorted(p(my_list))[::-1])
```

What `permutations` is is a generator. This yields every single permutations, but some will be equivalent.  It is in ascending order, as `sorted` gives the permutations from lowest to highest and `[::-1]` reverses it. For descending order, remove the splice (`[::-1]`). One without duplicates can make use of `sets` and the fact that `{0, 5, 6, 7} == {0, 7, 7, 5, 6, 0}`.

```
from itertools import permutations

def perm2(my_list):
    return " ".join(",".join((str(si) for si in i)) for i in reversed(sorted(set(p(my_list)))))
```

This shows a different way to reverse, using the `reversed` function, but is functionally the same.

You can make a function that takes (optional) `ascending` and `keep_duplicates` parameter will return in ascending order if ascending is True else in descending for ascending and `keep_duplicates` if True.

```
from itertools import permutations as p

def perm3(my_list, keep_duplicates=True, ascending=True):
    splice = -2 * reverse + 1 # -1 if True else 1
    if keep_duplicates:
        return " ".join(",".join((str(si) for si in i)) for i in sorted(p(my_list))[::splice])
    return " ".join(",".join((str(si) for si in i)) for i in sorted(set(p(my_list)))[::splice])
```

Comment: The OP wants a backtracking algorithm

Comment: I didn't see that. Sorry

Comment: well do u have any idea how to solve the repeats and Asc order things?

Comment: @user4464936 Found a solution to the ascending order and repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Add import:

```
from  itertools  import permutations
```

Repeatable permutation:

```
aux = [1,1,3]
#Repeatable permutations
for p in sorted(permutations(aux)):
    print p
```

And for no repeatable:

```
aux = [1,1,3]
listunique=[]
#No repeatable permutations 
for p in sorted(permutations(aux)):
    if p not in listunique:
        listunique.append(p)

for i in listunique:
    print i
```